# How can I restart coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am trying to implement a coroutine that moves an object to a specific point and then comes back to the origin (specified by me) as a coroutine in Unity, but the coroutine is not executed after returning to the origin. What's wrong?

```
public class LineManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 positionToGo = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
    IEnumerator coroutine;
    void Start()
    {
        coroutine = MoveToPosition(transform, positionToGo, 2f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(transform.position.y == 4)
        {
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Transform transform, Vector3 position, float timeToMove)
    {
        var currentPos = transform.position;
        var t = 0f;
        while (t < 1 && currentPos.y > position.y)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, position, t);
            yield return null;
        }
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 4, 0);
            StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    }
}
```

Comment: First as the last line of the coroutine. You dont need to call stop because it will stop when it leaves.   Second. Y probably doesn’t exactly equal 4.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to restart your routine for that.

But first things first:

```
transform.position.y == 4
```

is risky as it is a direct `float` comparison and might fail. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Anyways, back to the coroutine restarting. Why not simply move without a routine at all

```
public Vector3 positionToGo = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
public float timeToMove = 2f;

private Vector3 originalPosition;
private float factor;

private void Awake()
{
    originalPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(factor >= 1)
    {
        factor = 0;
        transform.position = originalPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        factor += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originalPosition, positionToGo, factor);
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative if you want to use the routine you can always simply make it loop

```
public Vector3 positionToGo = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
public float timeToMove = 2f;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    var originalPosition = transform.position;

    while(true)
    {
        for(var factor = 0f; factor < 1f; factor += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originalPosition, position, factor);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = originalPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the Coroutine in that IEnumerator with WaitForSeconds